# Question on Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus

Using Squeeze Theorem or otherwise, determine the following limit.

$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{(7n^4+ \sin(n))} $

My attempt, $ \sqrt[n]{7n^4} \leq \sqrt[n]{(7n^4+ \sin(n))} \leq \sqrt[n]{7n^4+1 } $

So, by Squeeze Theorem, $ lim_{n \to \infty}  \sqrt[n]{(7n^4+ \sin(n))} =1 $

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious that this inequality holds for arbitrary $n.$ Can you prove it?

Comment: I believe you need $\sqrt[n]{7n^4 - 1} \leq \sqrt[n]{(7n^4+ \sin(n))}$ for the inequality to be true since $-1 \leq \sin(n) \leq 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: But even then, @NicholasRoberts, the function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x}$ is not strictly increasing, so you cannot conclude that $f(g(x)) \leq f(h(x))$ whenever $g(x) \leq h(x).$

Comment: @Carlo I was thinking along the lines $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}=1 $

Comment: In fact, the function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x}$ is decreasing for all $x > e$ since the derivative has a factor of $(1 - \ln x),$ and the rest of the terms in the product are strictly positive. So, I think the OP should use this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Using logarithmic differentiation, observe that the function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x}$ has derivative $f'(x) = \frac{(1 - \ln x)}{x^2} f(x).$ Considering that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0,$ we have that $\frac{1}{x^2} f(x) > 0.$ Consequently, it follows that $f'(x) < 0$ for all $x > e$ so that $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing for all $x > e.$

Considering that $-1 \leq \sin n \leq 1,$ we have that $7n^4 - 1 \leq 7n^4 + \sin n \leq 7n^4 + 1,$ hence $$\sqrt[n]{7n^4 + 1} \leq \sqrt[n]{7n^4 + \sin n} \leq \sqrt[n]{7n^4 - 1}$$ for all integers $n > e.$ Can you finish the proof by Squeeze Theorem from here?

Comment: Carlo. $x^{1/n}$ is an increasing function of $x$: For $x <y$: $x^{1/n} <y^{1/n}$, implies $(7n^4-1)^{1/n} < f(x)<(7n^4+1)^{1/n}$. Your thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the $n$th root function is increasing. But we are dealing with the function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x}.$ Particularly, the exponent is the same variable as in the radicand.

Answer (score 0):

As  $(-1 \le sin(n) \le 1)$, the inequalities should be changed into:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{7n^4-1} \le \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{7n^4+sin(n)} \le \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{7n^4+1}$

and consequently $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{7n^4+sin(n)} =\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{7n^4+1}$.

However $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{7n^4+1}$ gives $(\frac{\infty}{\infty})$ indeterminacy. Let $X=\sqrt[n]{7n^4+1}
$

$$ ln X  = \frac{1}{n} \times ln(7n^4+1)
$$

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}ln X = lim(\frac{1}{n} \times ln(7n^4+1))
$$

$$ln (lim_{n\to \infty}X) = ln(\frac{\infty}{\infty}) $$

When we take derivative of both nominator and denominator of $(\frac{ln(7n^4+1)}{n})$ we get $(\frac{28n^3}{7n^4+1} )$

$$ln (lim_{n\to \infty}(\frac{28n^3}{7n^4+1} )) = ln(0) = -\infty $$